# Python Flask Gevent stack - Simple "Hello World" app shows as inefficient when benchmarked

Tags: python, gevent

I have the following simple "Hello World" app:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask
from gevent import wsgi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'Hello World'

server = wsgi.WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), app)
server.serve_forever()
```

As you can see it's pretty straightforward.

The problem is that despite such simpliness it's pretty slow/inefficient as the following benchmark (made with Apache Benchmark) shows:

```
ab -k -n 1000 -c 100 http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            5000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.515 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      146000 bytes
HTML transferred:       11000 bytes
Requests per second:    660.22 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       151.465 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.515 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          94.13 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.6      0       3
Processing:     1  145  33.5    149     191
Waiting:        1  144  33.5    148     191
Total:          4  145  33.0    149     191

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    149
  66%    157
  75%    165
  80%    173
  90%    183
  95%    185
  98%    187
  99%    188
 100%    191 (longest request)
```

Eventually increasing the number of connections and/or concurrency doesn't bring better results, in fact it becomes worse.

What I'm most concerned about is the fact that I can't go over 700 **Requests per second** and a **Transfer rate** of 98 Kbytes/sec.

Also, the individual **Time per request** seems to be too much.

I got curious about what Python and Gevent are doing in the background, or better, what the OS is doing, so I used a **strace** to determine eventual system-side issues and here's the result:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 56.46    0.000284           0      1386           close
 24.25    0.000122           0      1016           write
 10.74    0.000054           0      1000           send
  4.17    0.000021           0      3652      3271 open
  2.19    0.000011           0       641           read
  2.19    0.000011           0      6006           fcntl64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           waitpid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           time
  0.00    0.000000           0        12        12 access
  0.00    0.000000           0        32           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         5         1 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0      5006           gettimeofday
  0.00    0.000000           0         4         2 readlink
  0.00    0.000000           0       191           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 sigreturn
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0        21           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0        69        65 _llseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        71           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           getcwd
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0       243           mmap2
  0.00    0.000000           0      1838       748 stat64
  0.00    0.000000           0        74           lstat64
  0.00    0.000000           0       630           fstat64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getuid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getgid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           geteuid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getegid32
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           getdents64
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         1 futex
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_thread_area
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           epoll_ctl
  0.00    0.000000           0        12         1 epoll_wait
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0        26           clock_gettime
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           openat
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           eventfd2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           epoll_create1
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           bind
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           listen
  0.00    0.000000           0      1000           accept
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getsockname
  0.00    0.000000           0      2000      1000 recv
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           setsockopt
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000503                 24977      5103 total
```

As you can see there are 5103 errors, the worst offender being the **open** **syscall** which I suspect has to do with files not being found (**ENOENT**). To my surprise **epoll** didn't look like a *troubler*, as I heard of many horror stories about it.

I wish to post the full **strace** which goes into the detail of every single call, but it is way too large.

A final note; I also set the following system parameters (which are the maximum allowed amount) hoping it would change the situation but it didn't:

```
echo “32768 61000″ > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
sysctl -w fs.file-max=128000
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=300
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=61000
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=2500
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=2500
ulimit -n 1024
```

My question is, given that the sample I'm using can't be changed so much to fix these issues, where should I look to correct them?

**UPDATE**
I made the following "Hello World" script with Wheezy.web & Gevent and I got ~2000 Requests per second:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from gevent import pywsgi
from wheezy.http import HTTPResponse
from wheezy.http import WSGIApplication
from wheezy.routing import url
from wheezy.web.handlers import BaseHandler
from wheezy.web.middleware import bootstrap_defaults
from wheezy.web.middleware import path_routing_middleware_factory

def helloworld(request):
    response = HTTPResponse()
    response.write('hello world')
    return response


routes = [
    url('hello', helloworld, name='helloworld')
]


options = {}
main = WSGIApplication(
    middleware=[
        bootstrap_defaults(url_mapping=routes),
        path_routing_middleware_factory
    ],
    options=options
)


server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), main, backlog=128000)
server.serve_forever()
```

And the benchmark results:

```
ab -k -n 1000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            5000

Document Path:          /front
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   0.484 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      170000 bytes
HTML transferred:       11000 bytes
Requests per second:    2067.15 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       483.758 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.484 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          343.18 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    8  10.9      0      28
Processing:     2   78  39.7     56     263
Waiting:        2   78  39.7     56     263
Total:         18   86  42.6     66     263

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     66
  66%     83
  75%    129
  80%    131
  90%    152
  95%    160
  98%    178
  99%    182
 100%    263 (longest request)
```

I find Wheezy.web's speed great, but I'd still like to use Flask as it's simpler and less time consuming to work with.

Answer (score 1):

What gevent version are you using? Try simplifying your software stack to the bare minimum, and try the example they have on their github.

https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/wsgiserver.py

Are you comparing your benchmarks to a non-gevent version? I've aways had significant speedup with this library, so I would investigate a little further.

Comment: I have the latest version (1.0.1) and I'm just running that snippet as `python app.py` from the terminal. I have tried the example you linked and I get ~1400 requests per second and ~160 Kbytes/sec transfer rate, but as soon as I replace the application definition (beginning on line 7) with a Flask **route** (the same you see in my question) I'm back at the issues outlined in the benchmark. It looks like Flask routing is   a performance bottleneck at this point.

Comment: Don't worry too much about transfer rate. You won't hit max with lots of greenlets or threads returning a small string. Here's an article from 2010 benchmarking gevent, and in it, they show it hitting up to 8000 requests per second: http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers Maybe you need to tweak your benchmark utility? He uses autobench, not apache bench and provides the config used.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce what that guy did but the results weren't that much different. I think the problem is that Flask does a lot of route regex and other stuff in the background which explains the halved output compared to a simple one-route "hello world". No idea on how to fix it, but I heard that Bottle fixed their route implementation. There's also Wheezy.web which is ~3 times faster but a lot more complicated to set up.